# Is there a way to specific 'all except' in RunDeck ACLs?

Tags: acl, rundeck

In order to allow users to see a specific job but not actually be able to do anything with it I have the following in place in the relevant .aclpolicy file (edited down for brevity):

```
context:
  project: '.*'
for:
  job:
    - deny: [run,create,delete,kill,killAs,runAs,scm_create,scm_delete,scm_update,toggle_execution,toggle_schedule,update,read]
      equals:
        uuid: ee70e193-733c-4cb2-bdf0-0d6672da563f
    - allow: '*'
by:
  group: [users]
```

The `deny` line here is listing all available actions except `view`.  I want my users to have access to all other jobs (in the example above I have `'*'` for the allowed actions, just by way of example).

What I'm wondering is if there is a way to shorten the `deny` line to something like `- deny: [!view]` or something -- basically an "everything except view" shortcut.

While the above works, I'm worried that a future update might add in extra actions, and these will then be available for this job as they are not specifically denied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Rundeck ACLs denies all actions (works like a network firewall, denies all and you need to open step by step), in your case, you can use `- allow: [view]`.

EDIT: Right now doesn't exist a rule like the question.

Comment: Because I have that `- allow: '*'` in there, that's allowing full access to that job (and all jobs, which is what I want).  So I need to explicitly deny access to this specific job -- an explicit deny will override an implicit allow.

Comment: Yes, but if you leave - allow: [view] without "deny" sentence, rundeck denies all and just allow job view (it's like to use a hypothetical - deny: [!view]. Regards :-)

Comment: I had tried that and it didn't work.  The `- allow: '*'`, which give all access to all jobs, was giving full access to that Job.  The only way I could find to ensure that only `view` was available was to specifically deny everything else against the Job in question in order to override the `allow all to everything`.

Hence my question as to whether were was a shortcut instead of having to explicitly list all of the actions I wanted to deny.

Comment: I see, right now doesn't exist an explicit rule like !view. Regards! (my answer is updated).

Comment: Grand.  That's what I suspected.  Thanks for the clarification.